# How to measure the length of a pipe model

Tags: python

In the scene, there are many pipes. I want to get their length. Do you have any ideas[image]

My idea is to get one of the lines running through the whole pipe and measure the length of the line，But his line is irregular[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the pipes are made of curves, you can use animation nodes like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Python

accuracy to 3 significant digits (barely, but I was sloppy in modeling)

**Working with some assumptions:**

- the pipe consists of alternating segments: **straight** and **curve**
- **curve** is made of triangles only
- **straight** is made of quads only
- each quad in **straight** touches both **curve** segments (or the beginning/end of the pipe and one **curve** segment), meaning that each quad goes along whole **straight** segment
- ngon caps to easily detect reaching the end...

**Algorithm:**

- manually select starting and ending caps
- calculate current coordinates `curco` at the median point (center) of first cap
- check the length of the edge perpendicular to the selected ring, add it to the total pipe length, move `curco` by that distance in the same direction as the edge
- mark all quads connected to the starting ring to not be considered again
- traverse the triangles on the end of those quads, until another quad is found
- based on new quad select the next circle and calculate the median as `nextco`
- calculate 1/4 of circumference or a circle with radius being the distance between circles centers along a single axis:

[image]

repeat the algorithm until the end of pipe is reached.

```py
import bpy, bmesh
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Vector
from math import pi

me = C.active_object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

ring = [v for v in bm.select_history[0].verts]
endring = [v for v in bm.select_history[1].verts]


def median(ring):
    # median could be calculated using face, but I already wrote this, as my first assumption was no caps...
    l = len(ring)
    x = sum(v.co.x for v in ring) / l
    y = sum(v.co.y for v in ring) / l
    z = sum(v.co.z for v in ring) / l
    return Vector((x, y, z))
    

def traverse_quads(ring):
    disp = None
    nextring = []
    for v in ring:
        for e in v.link_edges:
            if not e.select:
                e.select_set(True)
                nextring.append(v2 := e.other_vert(v))
                if not disp:
                    disp = v2.co - v.co
    return disp.length, nextring 


def traverse_tris(ring):
    nextring = set()
    edges = {e for v in ring for e in v.link_edges if not e.select}
    more_edges = set()
    while edges:
        edge = edges.pop()
        edge.select_set(True)
        for f in edge.link_faces:
            selection = [e.select for e in f.edges]
            if len(selection) != 4 or all(selection):
                continue  # not quad or old quad
            nextring.add(edge.verts[0])
            nextring.add(edge.verts[1])
            break    
        else:  # new quad not found
            edges = edges.union(e for f in edge.link_faces for e in f.edges if not e.select)
    return list(nextring)


dist = 0
while True:
    edge = next(e for e in bm.edges if not e.select)
    pathlen, ring = traverse_quads(ring)
    dist += pathlen
    print("+= pathlen (", pathlen, ")")
    print(f"{dist=}")
    if ring[0] in endring:
        break
    curco = median(ring)
    ring = traverse_tris(ring)
    if ring[0] in endring:
        break
    nextco = median(ring)
    x_dist = abs(nextco.x - curco.x)
    y_dist = abs(nextco.y - curco.y)
    radius = max(x_dist, y_dist)
    dist += .5 * pi * radius
    print("+= .5 * pi * radius (", .5 * pi * radius, ")")
    print(f"{dist=}")

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Now create a curve, make it go in straight lines along parallel to X or Y axes, and make the curves circular (I was sloppy with this part), then measure the length of that curve (Chris' animation nodes trick, or convert to mesh and measureit), I got:

[image]

Now bevel the curve, dissolve unnecessary edges perpendicular to the curve's direction (it's important, as the script assumes they're not there), and triangulate the curved parts (again important, assumption):

[image]

As you can see, it's sloppy job, maybe that's why the script said `29.249520871844116` instead of `29.191`.

Comment: OMG…are u serious?!‍♂️+1 although i don’t understand it…